# How to get row as single-dimensional array from two-dimensional array by formula in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**For example:** 
I have a table:

```
A1:1 B1:2 C1:3 
A2:5 B2:6 C2:7
```

And I want to get a column with values:

```
E1: 1
E2: 2
E3: 3
E4: 5 
E5: 6
E6: 7
```

So any help would really be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It isn't clear from your example what the general rule should be - do you want the new "array" to list the values in ascending order or simply in the order shown in A1:C2.....or doesn't it matter?

Comment: simply in the order shown in A1:C2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get values from left to right from first row, then from second and so on, try this one:

- in `E1` formula `=A1`
- in `E2` formula `=INDEX($A$1:$C$2,1+INT(COUNTA($E$1:E1)/COLUMNS($A$1:$C$2)),1+MOD(COUNTA($E$1:E1),COLUMNS($A$1:$C$2)))`

and drag it down.

Note, this formula assumes that all your rows has the same column count (except maybe last row).

[image]

Comment: Thanks! You are really excel guru :)